# Clang error after using OpenFrameworks Project Generator

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, clang, openframeworks

I'm trying to update an [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc/) project using the [Project Generator](https://github.com/openframeworks/projectGenerator).

After updating the project, I'm now getting the following error in Xcode 8.2.1:

`clang: error: unknown argument: '-mmacosx-version-min'`

That flag is found in the Apple LLVM 8.0 - Custom Compiler Flags section of Build Settings in both my Project and Target:

[image]

Anyone have an idea on what the issue may be? I'm on macOS 10.12.1 Sierra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `-mmacosx-version-min` flag; `Xcode` uses `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`.

`MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` specifies the minimum version of `OS X` for the build target.

↳ [Configuring a Project for SDK-Based Development](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html)